# How to use GroupBy properly in LINQ?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, group-by

I have 4 tables: Post, Category, Relation and Meta

A `category` can contains multiple `posts`, and the relation between them is stored in `Relation` table. A post then can has many extra info that are stored in `Meta` table. I want to list all post with categories and extra infos, then group them by post's ID.

I have the following query

```
select p.ID, p.Title, t.Name, m.Key, m.Value from Post p
left join Relation r on p.ID = r.Child
left join Category c on r.Parent = c.ID
left join Meta m on p.ID = m.Object
where m.Type = 'news'
order by p.ID
```

and with these sample data:

```
Post

ID    Title

1     A

Category

ID    Name

1     Tips
2     Tricks

Meta

ID    Object  Key      Value

1       1     Key1     Value 1
2       1     Key2     Value 2

Relation

ID    Child Parent

1       1     1
2       1     2
```

then the result will be

```
PostID      Title     Category       Key      Value

  1           A         Tips         Key1     Value1
  1           A         Tips         Key2     Value2
  1           A        Tricks        Key1     Value1
  1           A        Tricks        Key2     Value2
```

and I expected the result to be

```
PostID      Title     Categories               Meta

  1           A      Tips, Tricks    Key1=Value1, Key2=Value2
```

I wonder if we can convert the query from SQL to `LINQ to Entities` with EF v4 and the result is stored in a class like this

```
class Result
{
  long ID,
  string Title,
  List<string> Categories,
  Dictionary<string, string> Meta
}
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the generated SQL doing with those extra selects? Is it small enough to post? Which database/EF backend - SQL Server?

Comment: I've added the SQL output. I'm using SQL Server with Entity Framework v4

Comment: In other words it's performing one query to look up the object IDs then a separate query to load each object. I'm really surprised it's doing that :-/

Comment: The left joins don't make sense, since your where clause limits on one of the joins. It is absolutely equivalent to make all of the joins inner.

Answer (score 1):

What's the final result you expect from the query
I personally prefer to write the query like

```
 var q = from r in Relation
         join p in Post on r.Child equals p.ID
         join t in Term on r.Parent equals t.ID
         let x = new { p.ID, p.Title, t.Name }
         group x by x.ID into g
         select g;
```

this way I think (not sure) the sql generated will be simpler

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not what I think it could be. I'll update the question soon ^^

Answer (score 1):

Now that you're wanting to use EntityFramework, you would merely need to set up you database, edmx with a Result table with an ID and a Title, then Category and Meta tables. Then add one-to-many relationships from the Result table to each the Category and Meta tables.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. I've already done all of them. I'm using EF right now and looking for a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but obviously if you're grouping, the results have to be grouped by anything in the resultset, or be aggregated data. This query will retrieve your results and group by PostId, PostTitle, and CategoryName, generating a single SQL Statement:

```
var query = from p in Posts
from r in Relations
.Where(r => p.ID == r.Child)
.DefaultIfEmpty()
from c in Categories
.Where(c => r.Parent == c.ID)
.DefaultIfEmpty()
group p by new {ID = p.ID, Title = p.Title, Name = c.Name} into z
select new { ID = z.Key.ID, Title = z.Key.Title, Name = z.Key.Name };
```

Here is the SQL Generated by this statement:

```
SELECT [t3].[ID], [t3].[Title], [t3].[value] AS [Name]
FROM (
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Title], [t2].[Name] AS [value]
FROM [Post] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Relation] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ID] = [t1].[Child]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Category] AS [t2] ON [t1].[Parent] = [t2].[ID]
) AS [t3]
GROUP BY [t3].[ID], [t3].[Title], [t3].[value]
```

Here is the SQL Generated by your original statement:

```
 SELECT [t0].[ID] AS [Key]
FROM [Post] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Relation] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ID] = [t1].[Child]
INNER JOIN [Category] AS [t2] ON [t1].[Parent] = [t2].[ID]
    GROUP BY [t0].[ID]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 Int SET @x1 = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Title], [t2].[Name]
FROM [Post] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Relation] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ID] = [t1].[Child]
INNER JOIN [Category] AS [t2] ON [t1].[Parent] = [t2].[ID]
WHERE ((@x1 IS NULL) AND ([t0].[ID] IS NULL)) OR ((@x1 IS NOT NULL) AND         ([t0].[ID]         IS     NOT NULL) AND (@x1 = [t0].[ID]))
    GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 Int SET @x1 = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Title], [t2].[Name]
FROM [Post] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Relation] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ID] = [t1].[Child]
INNER JOIN [Category] AS [t2] ON [t1].[Parent] = [t2].[ID]
WHERE ((@x1 IS NULL) AND ([t0].[ID] IS NULL)) OR ((@x1 IS NOT NULL) AND ([t0].[ID] IS     NOT NULL) AND (@x1 = [t0].[ID]))
```